# Android Studio - Hide Actionbar for specific urls in Webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-studio, android-actionbar

I have made an app with the help of Webview, but the action bar contains all the buttons that should be visible to the users those are logged in.

How can I hide the actionbar when the webview is on the login, register and lost password pages.

This way, the logged out users would not be able to see the actionbar as only these three pages would be visible to the logged out users.

Thanks
Have a nice day!

Comment: Create separate activities - one with no action bar for use with a web view, and one without?

Comment: Use `getSupportActionBar().hide();` & `getSupportActionBar().Show();` for hiding

Answer (score 0):

That really depends.

An obvious answer would be to override the following method:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)
```

then call `getActionbar().show();` or `getActionbar().hide();` OR their support counterparts.

The non-obvious problem will be if the login, register pages do not use a separate URL and instead make use of Javascript. If this is the case you will have to call `addJavascriptInterface` and add an object to interface with your Javascript. I have not done this before but the Android Webview guide has [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript).

Comment: `public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                  if (url==("http//hifella.com/login")) {
               getActionBar().hide();
            }

    }`

I have tried the above code but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?